# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): _Map_base::at

Tags: c++

I am using an unordered map in order to create an adjacency list for storing flight information.

When I run my code I am getting the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
   what():  _Map_base::at
```

I am a bit new to C++ and do not understand what this means. **I know that it is because of the use of `.at()` in the `getDestinations()` function, but how do I fix this?**

Code below:

**graph.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

//creates a struct for cities with name and isInternational variables
struct City {
  string name; //name stored in variable of type string
  bool isInternational; //boolean variable for if city is international or not
};

//creates graph class with function prototypes
class Graph {
  public:
    //function prototypes for adding cities, adding flights, and determining flight possibility
    void addCity(const string& name, bool isInternational);
    void addFlight(const string& from, const string& to);
    bool canReach(const string& from, const string& to);

    //function prototypes for retrieving cities & destinations
    vector<City> getCities() const;
    vector<City> getDestinations(const string& from) const;
  private:
    //uses unordered map to create lists for both cities & flights
    unordered_map<string, City> cities;
    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> flights;
};
```

```
//function definition for getDestinations function
vector<City> Graph::getDestinations(const string& from) const {
  vector<City> result;
  for (const auto& destination : flights.at(from)) {
    result.push_back(cities.at(destination));
  }
  return result; 
}
```

I've tried to use different methods to access the `from` & `destination` attributes, such as `contains()` or `find()`, but they are not working.

Comment: It means `cities.at(destination)` does not exist for some `destination` you have in your `flights`

Comment: The error could also be coming from `flights.at(from)` instead, meaning there is no flight information for the city they are coming from.

Comment: Good on you for using `at` instead of `[]`. Saved yourself from a much harder time debugging why new-and-empty items miraculously appeared in the map.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at) of `std::unordered_map` says that `std::out_of_range` is thrown if the key you are searching for is not in the map.

In this case you could use the [vector::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) method and check the returned value against [vector::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/end) value to do the same task in a safe way:

```
std::vector<City> Graph::getDestinations(const std::string &from) const {
    std::vector<City> result;
    auto it = flights.find(from);
    if (it == flights.end()) {
        // flight does not exist
        return {};
    }
    const auto &[key, value] = *it;
    for (const auto& destination : value) {
        /* I am asuming that the relationship between cities and flights
            is internally managed by your Graph class.
            In that case you don't need to check with find here.
        */
        result.push_back(cities.at(destination));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use contains in C++20 in order to confirm the existence of a specified key-value pair.
Only if the key is valid, you can access the corresponding value. However, make sure you don't use contains in a multiset or multimap.

```
unordered_map<int, string>map;
/*some insertions*/
int key{1};
if(map.contains(key))
{
  /* you can not acess the key-value */
}
else
{
  /* you can acess the key-value sucessfully */
  map.at(key) = "hello,world";
}
```